# Is that "the most" or just "most" to be used for a superlative of an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, definite-articles, modifiers

I wonder whether to use the determinant "the" when it is to be used for superlative of an adverb as follows:

> (A) These neurons innervate **most** densely to layer 1.
>
> (B) These neurons innervate **the most** densely to layer 1.

In these real examples, what the sentences try to convey is that "These neurons innervate layer 1 with the highest density."

I feel like A is better. However, because of the lack of "the", it might fail to mean that the innervation was the densest in the layer 1.

Additional simpler examples to avoid complexity related to terminologies. I can't really think of many ***ly adverb. It's a bit awkward, but I believe it shows my point.

> (A) The red car runs **most** smoothly among those cars.
>
> (B) The red car runs **the most** smoothly among those cars.

Comment: You can say "the most densely" if you prefer, in which case the determiner "the" is analysed as modifying the comparative quantifier "most". In fact, I suspect it would be the most frequently used of the two.

Comment: Why are you even saying that neurons innervate densely?? **Neuron density** is a thing. So: neuron density is **greatest** in or at layer 1.

Comment: This question was 6 years ago, and now I see it, I find many problems by myself. Apart from that, neuronal density, i.e. how many neurons are in a unit volume, and a group of neurons densely innervating an area or layer are very different things. The latter can be a sparsely distributed small number of cells that send axons to the target and have huge arborization with many branches there.

Answer (score 1):

I think both A and B are awkward.  If you replace innervate with either of its definitions:

(A) These neurons supply with nerves most densely to the layer 1.

(A) These neurons stimulate most densely to the layer 1.

Also, "the layer 1" seems like an awkward way to address the first layer.

How about: **These neurons innervate layer 1 with the most density.**

As far as whether you should say "the most" or "most", consider:

- Most people are friendly. = The majority of people are friendly.
- The most people are friendly. = nonsense
- I am the most friendly person in the room. = I am, to the highest degree of all people in the room, the friendliest.
- I am most friendly person in the room. = nonsense

So "most" means "the majority of", while "the most" refers to the greatest degree or quantity of all values.

Comment: The "the layer 1" is my mistake actually. "Innervate" refers to sending or supplying nerves, or if the subject is a neutron, axons, (as is in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/innervate) so it does not mean "stimulate". Those neurons can be inhibitory. But these things are all about terminology. My point was not there. I quite like you final suggestion (I appreciate that and I may use it), but you didn't really answered my question. You mean "most" should not be used for this purpose?

Comment: I edited my answer.  Does that answer your question?  I'm also not sure why your question was downvoted... People should leave feedback for those with low reputations.

Comment: For final clarification, "These neurons innervate layer 1 with the most density." means that those particular neurons innervate layer 1 with more density than any other relevant group of neurons (whether they innervate with **the majority of density** or not). --- "These neurons innervate layer 1 with most density." indicates that those particular neurons innervate layer 1 with **at least half of the available density**.(Which we see doesn't really make sense in this context.)

Comment: Sorry, I immediately took the down vote by you, because at that you were the only one here! This was my first entry to this web site and I went a bit emotional. Apologies if my previous response offended you even slightest.

Comment: I have no problem using "most" and "the most" as long as they modify nouns or adjectives. I can distinguish your four examples without a problem. An ambiguity arises when you want to use a superlative to modify an adverb. In my example, purpose of the sentence is to mention the highest density rather than a majority; in other words, "most" or "the most" as the superlative of the adverb "densely".

Comment: majority of density is a **no-go**.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'most' can act as a logical quantifier of a noun (most neurons), or an intensifier of an adjective or adverb (most dense or most densely).  The determiner 'the' only applies to a noun (the (most dense) innervation).

Answer (score 0):

I did my own research. Found this [link](http://studyenglish.at.webry.info/201503/article_5.html).

According "to Practical English Usage"

> "The" is sometimes dropped before superlative adverbs in an informal
>   style. 
>   Who can run (the) fastest?

This means that you can put "the" to "most densely", if I prefer.